# ggplot without facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-mice

The following code, from @ROLO in answer to my earlier question generates 3 plots:

```
require(mice)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)
dt <- nhanes
impute <- mice(dt, seed = 23109)

# Obtain the imputed data, together with the original data
imp <- complete(impute,"long", include=TRUE)
# Melt into long format
imp <- melt(imp, c(".imp",".id","age"))
# Add a variable for the plot legend
imp$Imputed<-ifelse(imp$".imp"==0,"Observed","Imputed")

# Plot. Be sure to use stat_density instead of geom_density in order
#  to prevent what you call "unwanted horizontal and vertical lines"
ggplot(imp, aes(x=value, group=.imp, colour=Imputed)) + 
    stat_density(geom = "path",position = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=2, scales="free")
```

[image]

My question is, how do I modify this to plot each one individually ?

Comment: This is just a comment so that @ROLO get's notified, who wrote this code in answer to my earlier question.

Comment: Just do that exact plot three times on each subset of the data?

Comment: @joran Thanks ! That worked great - I just did `imp <- imp[imp$variable=='bmi',]` before the call to ggplot and similar for the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joran said, you can just use a subset of the data in each plot.

```
ggplot(imp[imp$variable=="bmi",], aes(x=value, group=.imp, colour=Imputed)) + 
    stat_density(geom = "path",position = "identity")
ggplot(imp[imp$variable=="hyp",], aes(x=value, group=.imp, colour=Imputed)) + 
    stat_density(geom = "path",position = "identity")
ggplot(imp[imp$variable=="chl",], aes(x=value, group=.imp, colour=Imputed)) + 
    stat_density(geom = "path",position = "identity")
```

Alternatively, you could put these in a loop

```
library("plyr")
d_ply(imp, .(variable), function(DF) {
    print(ggplot(DF, aes(x=value, group=.imp, colour=Imputed)) + 
        stat_density(geom = "path",position = "identity"))
})
```

The downside of this approach is that it puts all the plots out one right after the other so there is no chance to see the previous ones on the screen.  If you are outputting to a PDF (directly or via something like `knitr`), all will get written and can be seen that way.